# why $t_n\to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let  $(t_n)$  and $(v_n)$ be two sequence such that $\forall n\in\Bbb N: 0\leq t_n\leq 1$ and $v_n\geq 0$ with $v_n\to 0$.
Assume  $\forall n\in\Bbb N: 0\leq t_{n+1}\leq \frac{t_n+v_n}{M}$ where  $M>1$.
Why $t_n\to 0$.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

$0 \leq t_{n+1} \leq \frac{t_{n}+v_{n}}{M}$. Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$, we get

$0 \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}{t_{n+1}} \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{t_{n}+v_{n}}{M} \implies 0 \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}{t_{n+1}} \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{t_{n}}{M} $

Now, notice that, $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_{n+1}$ must equal $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_{n}$. Call it L. So,

$0\leq L \leq \frac{L}{M}$. Which for $M>1$ is possible if and only if $L=0$ as desired.

Comment: Before you have to prove that this limit $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} t_n$ exists.

Comment: @100nanoFarad not really, since by hypothesis $0 \leq t_{n} \leq 1$ for all $n$, meaning the limit must be finite.

Comment: $0\leq|\sin(n)|\leq1$ but the limit does not exist

Comment: yep, you're right, im a moron

Comment: Any ideas for such an proof?

Comment: Consider the sequence $s_n=sup_{k\geq n}\{t_k\}$, it is monotonic decreasing, so its limit exists. It results  $s_{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{M}(s_n+ sup_{k\geq n}v_k)$ and then, in a way similar of what you proved, $s_n\rightarrow0$. Obviously $0\leq t_n \leq s_n$ therefore  $t_n\rightarrow0$.